# How do I prove this statement about permutations contained in the centralizer?

Tags: permutations

> I have given the following permutation $$\sigma=\left(\begin{array}{rrr} 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9 \\ 4&5&6&7&8&9&1&2&3 \end{array}\right)$$ and $I_1=\{1,4,7\},I_2=\{2,5,8\}, I_3=\{3,6,9\}$. I just know that $\sigma(I_i)=I_i$ for all $i$. Now we have given $\tau\in C_{S_9}(\sigma)$ the centralizer. I need to show that $\tau(I_i)\in \{I_1,I_2,I_3\}$.

We just know that $$\tau(I_1)=\tau(\sigma(I_1))=\sigma(\tau(I_1))$$. Now I only need to show that $\tau(I_1)\in \{I_1,I_2,I_3\}$. But I don't see why this needs to be true. Could someone help me?

Comment: In these situations, cycle notation is very helpful.  Do you know it?  That's because cycle notation allows you very easily to compute $\tau^{-1} \sigma \tau$.

Comment: but I don't know anything about $\tau$. So I don't see why this is helpful

Comment: You  know a lot about $\tau$.  You know that $\tau^{-1} \sigma \tau = \sigma$.  When you write the expression in cycle notation that gives you a strong constraint on $\tau$.  It's easy to see this way, for instance, that there are exactly $162$ elements of the centralizer of $\sigma$.

Comment: Sorry I don't see your point, and neither how to write $\tau$ in a cyclic notation

Comment: Can you write $\sigma$ in cycle notation?  And do you know how to calculate $\tau^{-1} \sigma \tau$ in general when $\sigma$ is written in cycle notation?

Comment: Start with writing $\sigma$ rather than $\tau$ in cycle notation, and figure out how conjugation generally works on a permutation written in cycle notation. (In contrast to $\sigma$, it doesn't seem to be particularly illuminating to think of $\tau$ in terms of its cycle decomposition here).

Comment: Yes so I know that $\sigma=(147)(258)(369)$ and I know how in general one can calculate $\tau^{-1}\sigma \tau$

Comment: So how must $\tau^{-1}$ look if $$(1\,4\,7)(2\,5\,8)(3\,6\,9) = (\tau^{-1}(1)\;\tau^{-1}(4)\;\tau^{-1}(7))(\tau^{-1}(2)\;\tau^{-1}(5)\;\tau^{-1}(8))(\tau^{-1}(3)\;\tau^{-1}(6)\;\tau^{-1}(9)) $$ ? (It would probably be simpler to start out with $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=\sigma$ instead).

Comment: Sorry I don't see how you get to the left side, since for example I need to compute $\tau^{-1}(\sigma(\tau(1)))$ but I don't know $\tau(1)$

Comment: You said you know how to calculate $\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau$? If what I wrote doesn't match that knowledge, could you describe the procedure you do know?

Comment: So we learned that for example to compute $\tau^{-1}(\sigma(\tau(1))$ we take the element on the right of $\tau$ then the one on the right of $\sigma(\tau(1))$ and so on

Comment: I'm not speaking about how to _apply_ $\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau$ to a particular element, but how to write down the _entire_ cycle decomposition for $\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau$ when you know the cycle decomposition of $\sigma$. Do you know, for example, that for a _single_ cycle we have $$ \alpha(x_1\,x_2\,\ldots\,x_n)\alpha^{-1} = (\alpha(x_1)\;\alpha(x_2)\;\ldots\;\alpha(x_n))$$

Comment: Yes we saw this in the lecture. But here we have three cycles?

Comment: So I have looked at it and your computation from above makes sense. So I would say that $\tau^{-1}=\sigma$ is this correct? and thus $$\tau=(741)(852)(369)$$ and thus $\tau(I_i)\in \{I_1,I_2,I_3\}$

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you're misunderstanding the exercise. Your comments sound like you think there is one _particular_ permutation $\tau$ that the exercise wants a proof about -- but it actually asks for a proof that such-and-such is true about _every_ permutation in the centralizer (all 162 of them, as Robert computed).

Comment: Hmm okei so I‘m really missunderstanding this part. Could you maybe explain more sbout it, because I don‘t understand how it should look like

Comment: because I don't see how to get from this $\tau^{-1}(1)...$ term to tau since this therm is not tau it is equal to sigma